# convert to date format in pyqt5 Qprinter

Tags: python, pyqt5, qprinter, qdatetime

Is there a way to convert to date format will use the Printer and QTextDocument the result always show in the date and time like in the image?

this is my code

```
def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):

        model_hjd = QSqlTableModel()
        model_hjd.setTable('transactions')
       
        date = str(self.dateEdit_10.text())
        date_2 = str(self.dateEdit_14.text())

        self.tableView_22.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        model_hjd.setSort(6, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        self.tableView_22.setModel(model_hjd)
        model_hjd.select()
        filter_ft = "date_d BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'" % (date, date_2)
        model_hjd.setFilter(filter_ft)

        self.tableView_22.setModel(model_hjd)

        document = QTextDocument()
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)
        tableFormat = QTextTableFormat()
        table = cursor.insertTable(model_hjd.rowCount() + 1, model_hjd.columnCount(), tableFormat)
        myheaders = []
        for i in range(0, model_hjd.columnCount()):
            myheader = model_hjd.headerData(i, Qt.Horizontal)
            cursor.insertText(myheader)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)

        for row in range(0, model_hjd.rowCount()):
           for col in range(0, model_hjd.columnCount()):
               index = model_hjd.index( row, col )
               cursor.insertText(str(index.data()))
               cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCell)
        document.print_(printer)
```

but the result in date and time are like this

[image]

Comment: Did you try with PyQt5 by importing and converting it?

Comment: the time and date in the database are fine and in a date and time format but whene i try to print the result like the image ( pyqt5.qtcore.qdate(2020,8,8) ) i want to print only the date and time

Comment: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/datetime/ try this

Comment: thank you BijinAbraham  but @Heike solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom function to format the different types of data in your table, e.g.

```
@staticmethod
def to_string(entry):
    if isinstance(entry, (QtCore.QDate, QtCore.QTime, QtCore.QDateTime)):
        return entry.toString(Qt.SystemLocaleShortDate)
    else:
        return str(entry)

def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
    ....
    cursor.insertText(self.to_string(index.data()))
    ....
```

Comment: change `if any(isinstance(entry, tt) for tt in (QtCore.QDate, QtCore.QTime, QtCore.QDateTime)):` to `if isinstance(entry, (QtCore.QDate, QtCore.QTime, QtCore.QDateTime)):`

Comment: Thanks @eyllansec.I didn't know isinstance could handle collections of types.